# RecyclerView doesn't update indices of elements after deletion

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have this project where I have a list of tasks and I have a Button to delete a task in a RecyclerView. The thing is that whenever I delete an element the positions of the following element positions are not updated and in the case that I have 2 tasks, for example, I delete the first one, everything's fine, but when I try to delete the second one I get the IndexOutOfBoundsException().

This is part of my code.

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull viewHolder holder, final int position) {

    holder.actividad.setText(lista.get(position).getActividad());
    String hora=lista.get(position).getHoraInicio().substring(0,2)+":";
    hora+=lista.get(position).getHoraInicio().substring(2);
    hora+=" a ";
    hora+=lista.get(position).getHoraFin().substring(0,2)+":";
    hora+=lista.get(position).getHoraFin().substring(2);
    holder.hora.setText(hora);

    holder.btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            deleteActivity(position);
        }
    });

}
private void deleteActivity(int position){

    Log.i("INFO","Pressed the position "+position);
    deleteTask(lista.get(position).getId());
    lista.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `notifyItemRemoved(position)` does not necessarily cause the remaining items to be rebound.
You can use `notifyDataSetChanged()` instead. `notifyDataSetChanged()` always causes full rebind of all elements and in your case, it will update the index.

Just replace `notifyItemRemoved(position)` with `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is on below 2 lines. Please move those lines within the response on your asynchronous request(deleteTask(...)).

```
   lista.remove(position);
   notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

Below line of code performs an asynchronous call and thus your other 2 lines above will not necessarily be called after the line of code.

```
deleteTask(lista.get(position).getId());
```